# AppleScript to open all files in a folder, one by one. Alias list to carry filename for pasting later?

Tags: applescript, filemaker, finder

I have hundreds of custom FileMaker Pro .fp7 files that I need to Open, menu item "Export Script..." for and save. Here's what I have so far.

```
tell application "Finder"
set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/EDITOR/Desktop/DROP/" as alias list
end tell
repeat with f in fl
tell application "FileMaker Pro"open f
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "FileMaker Pro"
        click menu item "Export Script..." of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "FileMaker Pro" of application "System Events"
        delay 0.4
        keystroke "/Users/EDITOR/Desktop/DROP/"         
    end tell
end tell
end repeat
```

My challenge is this: FileMaker Pro wont carry the filename into the Export name window. It only says Untitled.tab. Is there a way to either source and copy the filename as it's being opened or alias'd? Either hold it in the clipboard to paste later...or, have the repeat function pause for me to type each .tab filename.

Thanks,
G.

Comment: FileMaker Pro actually has it's own **Applescript Dictionary**, which means it's scriptable, or that you can write code straight to it without having to use UI scripting. Take a look here: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.04/ScriptingFileMakerPro/index.html

Comment: Why so many database files?

Comment: Unfortunately, these DBs are instances of one file custom written for the film industry with 1 unique purpose and unscriptable.

Comment: Make one single db by importing them together

Comment: Each DB file is a scene of the script for continuity coverage. A tool for the script supervisor on set, marking which takes cover what action & dialogue.

Comment: Talk to FileMaker to get the filename : "name of window 1" gives you the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Import all database files into one master version. Without this step FileMaker is unusable.

It is then easy to generate the smaller fm files with detail data out of the master.

Comment: Code to help me out is what I'm after. I can't merge the databases.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

One -- if you're using Filemaker Pro 9, 10, 11, or 12 (possibly earlier versions too, I'm not sure,) you could write a custom script in Filemaker that uses the Export Records script step, programmatically specifying (through a local or global variable) a custom file name for each export. Be sure when you set the variable that you include the appropriate extension depending on what format you export to, i.e.  .csv, .tab, .xls, etc.

Once you get the script working correctly, tick the "Perform without dialog" option so it will process & exit silently without you having to interact with each export action.

[image]

Two - If all else fails, you might look into using a third-party keyboard / scripting utility called "[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)". It has *lots* of functionality, including the ability to interact via Applescript and, I believe, to pass args to and from shell scripts.

Possibly "[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)" could be used to paste the filename into FMP's export/save-as... dialog box.

Comment: Appreciated, and we're using FMPro 10 but this isn't a typical DB. It's been specifically coded to operate one way and much of FMP's functionality has been locked or removed.

Comment: I didn't understand (till now) that you're dealing with a locked "run-time" solution. Your best option is probably something involving Keyboard Maestro and a simple return-separated list of file names to loop through & execute all the necessary exports.